# Unable to use np.mean and np.std on a groupby object

Tags: python

I have a groupeby object from pytho pandas. I can use np.sum method on the grouped object and the size method. However, it gives me a error message when I try to use np.mean and np.std method.

```
3093         if len(new_blocks) == 0:
-> 3094             raise DataError('No numeric types to aggregate')
3095 
3096         return data.items, new_blocks
DataError: No numeric types to aggregate
```

My code for the operation is below:

```
 # create a groupby object. the groupby key is 0 
 final_grouped = final.groupby(0)
 # call the sum function on the grouped by object
 y = final_grouped.aggregate(np.sum)
 # call the size method on the grouped object
 y['size']=final_grouped.size()
 # call the std and mean function on the grouped object
 print(final_grouped.agg(np.mean))
```

The data looks like this:

```
      index               0              population
0   United Kingdom      Europe             63.871
1   Brazil              South America      205.915
2   Russian Federation  Europe             143.5
3   Germany             Europe             80.3697
4   Spain               Europe             46.4434
```

Comment: That means your columns aren't of numeric type. Can you please provide a sample of your data?

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ I have provided some data sample